# Typescript discriminated union types with Observable.of

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, discriminated-union

I'm trying to use Typescript 2.0's discriminated union types with RxJS, but I'm getting an error that the object I am returning is not of the one of the types of the union type.

Here are my types:

```
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  width: number;
}

interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}

interface Center {
  kind: "center";
}

type Shape = Square | Circle | Center;
```

This function where I just return a `Shape` not using an `Observable` compiles completely fine:

```
function shapeFactory(width: number): Shape {
  if (width > 5) {
    return {kind: "circle", radius: width};
  } else if (width < 2) {
    return {kind: "square", width: 3};
  }

  return {kind: "center"};
}
```

When I instead try to return an `Observable<Shape>` like so:

```
function shapeFactoryAsync(width: number): Observable<Shape> {
  if (width > 5) {
    return Observable.of({kind: "circle", radius: width});
  } else {
    return Observable.of({kind: "center"});
  }
}
```

I am met with the compilation error:

```
Type 'Observable<{ kind: string; radius: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Shape>'.
  Type '{ kind: string; radius: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Shape'.
    Type '{ kind: string; radius: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Center'.
      Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"center"'.
```

I expect that my first return would be of type `Observable<{ kind: "circle"; radius: number; }>`, since `kind` is the discriminate across all `Shape` types.  Strangely, it is okay with `Observable.of({kind: "center"})`, possibly because there's no other data associated with it?

I am able to fix it if I explicitly assign the object and give the assignment a type like so:

```
let circle: Circle = {kind: "circle", radius: width};
return Observable.of(circle);
```

Though this seems like it should be an unnecessary cast.

Am I just doing this completely wrong or is that cast necessary in order to figure out that `kind` is supposed to be of value `"circle"` instead of type `string`?

Comment: It seems that this compiles fine now - the compiler is smarter now. There may still be some cases where you need to put `kind: <circle> 'circle'` or the newer `kind: <const> 'circle'` to force it to be the 'circle' type as opposed to the 'circle' string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a call like `Observable.of({ kind: "center" })`, TypeScript is unable to infer the type from the anonymous argument.

You can solve your problem by specifying the [type variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) as `Shape` when calling the generic `of` method:

```
function shapeFactoryAsync(width: number): Observable<Shape> {
  if (width > 5) {
    return Observable.of<Shape>({ kind: "circle", radius: width });
  } else {
    return Observable.of<Shape>({ kind: "center" });
  }
}
```

With the type variable specified, TypeScript no longer has to infer the type.

Comment: Is this because `Observable.of` is a static function?  Had I a `subject: Subject<T>` for instance, then it should be able to understand `typeof t === T` when calling `subject.next(t)`?

Comment: Yep. If you had a `Subject<Shape>` its `next` would not effect the error mentioned in your question.

Comment: You could also put `of<Circle>(...)` and still have `Observable<Shape>` for the overall return type.